# How to define JavaScript variable inside loop, then call it outside (scope)

Tags: php, javascript, html, scope

I can't seem to get either variable report1 or report2 to have a global scope, I know this problem seems really basic, but I just can't seem to find an answer.

I have to define the variable report1 when `numClicks == 1`, and then report2 when `numClicks == 2`. But JavaScript is forgetting the variables as soon as numClicks changes, which is understandable. However, I just cannot seem to widen the scope of the variables. I know for PHP you can do something like `return $variable` to make it global, but nothing is really working here in JavaScript.

```
              <?
                "<img  height =\"16\"  src = \"images/stapler.png\"  
                onclick=\"

                    numClicks++;
                if(numClicks == 1){
                    var report1 = '".$reports[$i]."';
                }
                if(numClicks == 2){
                    var report2 = '".$reports[$i]."';
                }
                return confirm(report1);

                \">\n";?>
```

When the script is executed, on the third click it is returning `undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you use the `var` syntax, you are redeclaring the variable.

You need to define the `var report1; var report2;` outside of your functions in the global scope; within your function, just do a plain assignment (i.e. `report2 = ...;`)

Comment: Doh! I knew it must be simple

Comment: Actually, you don't need to declare the variable at all, just use it!

Answer (score 1):

Using "var" will make the variable local to the scope.  By eliminating that keyword, it will be global.

(Overly simplified, but that's the basic trick.)

Answer (score 1):

To give a global scope to a variable, just omit the "var" keyword:

```
 report1 = '".$reports[$i]."';
```